# Deploy contract as Authority in Parity PoA private chain

Tags: contract-deployment, parity, proof-of-authority

I deployed a Proof of Authority chain with 2 nodes, but when I try to deploy a contract with one authority account, it says that there is unsufficient fund in the account.

I though PoA didn't rely on mining, so how can i "mine" in my authority account in order to get enough funds to deploy my smart contract ?

Answer (score 1):

Mining refers to the act of issuing blocks. In POW, it requires hashpower to find new blocks, in POA, new blocks can be issued by selected authority addresses.

Since you are in control of the mining, you can allow miner to accept transactions with gas price as zero. When sending the transaction, use gas price as zero, and then you will be able to mine your transactions.

Additionally, you can give balance to any account by including it in the list of accounts in genesis file.